# WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2063' ('MQRC_SECURITY_ERROR')

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm WAS 7 and Webshpere MQ 6 for JMS Application in java.
I'm facing this error while connecting to the queue.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'Test_QManager' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '172.21.136.72'. Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2063' ('MQRC_SECURITY_ERROR').
Any Help Please.

Comment: Did you setup a MCAUSER in the SVRCONN channel used by WAS7 to connect to MQ6?  Is that a valid user, ie is it available locally or in LDAP, properly configured?

Comment: The error reported in the queue manager error log will tell you the reason why the queue manager gave your application a 2063. Please can you provide that information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, the most detail for any security error is provided at the queue manager.  The reason for this is that the administrator needs as much information as possible but an attacker should get as little information as possible.

This gives us a great diagnostic tool for this kind of error.  When at the client you get a very sparse "security error" with little explanation, look at the queue manager's logs.  If they record a detailed error at the same time as your client did, then you know the request made it to MQ and why MQ rejected it.

However, if the QMgr logs do not record the error then you know to concentrate your efforts on the client side.

If this was an authorization error, you would get back a `2035`.  A `2063` has something to do with security but not authorization.  That leaves things like the client cannot find or open its keystore, or the file permissions on the keystore allow world-read.  It might be that the client JSSE provider isn't compatible with MQ.

The recommended diagnostic is to use the sample programs that come with MQ to perform verification tests.  If these can recreate the problem, it is with configuration or the environment.  If they work, then the issue is likely in the code, app server config, or managed objects.  Turning on client-side trace should help tremendously, just remember to disable it afterwards,